# How to draw two independent lines with recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Here is my data

```
const DATA = [

 {
    name: '0',
    data: [
      {x: "07/16/20 01:50", y: "0.397"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:51", y: "0.480"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:52", y: "0.416"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:53", y: "0.396"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:54", y: "0.418"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:55", y: "0.390"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '1',
    data: [
      {x: "07/16/20 04:54", y: "0.384"},
      {x: "07/16/20 05:57", y: "0.432"}
    ],
  }

]
```

I am trying to plot these points but failing.

Answer (score 0):

In your data structure, you need to have the general array of data objects only. Here, you are trying to have sub data arrays, that's probably why the graphs won't display.

I assumed you wanted to have a simple line graph, so tweaking your data array, it could result into this:

```
const customData = [
  {x: "07/16/20 01:50", y: "0.397"},
  {x: "07/16/20 02:51", y: "0.480"},
  {x: "07/16/20 02:52", y: "0.416"},
  {x: "07/16/20 02:53", y: "0.396"},
  {x: "07/16/20 02:54", y: "0.418"},
  {x: "07/16/20 02:55", y: "0.390"},
  {x: "07/16/20 04:54", y2: "0.384"},
  {x: "07/16/20 05:57", y2: "0.432"}
]
```

Where `x` is the label to use on the XAxis, `y` the data for `name: '0'` in your data structure, and `y2` for `name: '1'`.

The resulted graph would look like this in the code, where there would be two distinct lines; one for the `y1` values, and the other for the `y2` values.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={customData}
    >
      <XAxis dataKey="x" />
      <YAxis />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="y"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="y2"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      />
    </LineChart>
  );
}
```

[image]